# How should I understand `let _ as s = "abc" in s ^ "def"` in OCaml?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

`let _ as s = "abc" in s ^ "def"`

**So how should understand this?**

---

I guess it is some kind of `let pattern = expression` thing?

**First**, what's the meaning/purpose/logic of `let pattern = expression`?

**Also**, in `pattern matching`, I know there is `pattern as identifier` usage, in `let _ as s = "abc" in s ^ "def"`, `_` is pattern, but behind `as`, it is an expression `s = "abc" in s ^ "def"`, not an `identifier`, right?

*edit*:

**finally**, how about this: `(fun (1 | 2) as i -> i + 1) 2`, is this correct?

I know it is wrong, but why? `fun pattern -> expression` is allowed, right?

---

I really got lost here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `let pattern = expr1 in expr2` is pretty central to OCaml. If the pattern is just a name, it lets you name an expression. This is like a local variable in other language. If the pattern is more complicated, it lets you destructure `expr1`, i.e., it lets you give names to its components.

In your expression, behind `as` is just an identifier: `s`. I suspect your confusion all comes down to this one thing. The expression can be parenthesized as:

```
let (_ as s) = "abc" in s ^ "def"
```

as Andreas Rossberg shows.

Your final example is correct if you add some parentheses. The compiler/toplevel rightly complains that your function is partial; i.e., it doesn't know what to do with most ints,
only with 1 and 2.

**Edit**: here's a session that shows how to add the parentheses to your final example:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.00.0

# (fun (1 | 2) as i -> i + 1) 2;;
Error: Syntax error
# (fun ((1 | 2) as i) -> i + 1) 2;;
Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a value that is not matched:
0
- : int = 3
#
```

**Edit 2**: here's a session that shows how to remove the warning by specifying an exhaustive set of patterns.

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.00.0

# (function ((1|2) as i) -> i + 1 | _ -> -1) 2;;
- : int = 3
# (function ((1|2) as i) -> i + 1 | _ -> -1) 3;;
- : int = -1
#
```

Comment: in my final example, `(1 | 2) as i` should have priority, right?

Comment: It would be nice to have an OCaml standard, but for now I'd say the compiler is the authority on the language! In `parser.y` you'll see that `MINUSGREATER` has higher precedence than `AS`. So the parentheses are required.

Comment: ok, so how to make `(fun ((1 | 2) as i) -> i + 1) 2;;` correct? can I write `(fun (((1|2) as i) -> i+1 | _ -> -1)) 2`? just add other cases

Comment: `fun` takes just one pattern. You can use `function` with multiple patterns. See **Edit 2**.

Answer (score 5):

The grouping is `let (_ as s) = "abc"` -- which is just a convoluted way of saying `let s = "abc"`, because `as` with a wildcard pattern `_` in front is pretty much useless.